# JRE source files in eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse

I currently have eclipse setup to step through the class files in the rt.jar from my JDK installation (JAVA_HOME\jre\lib). It looks like eclipse by default opens up a class file from the jar. But stepping through a class file does not show me variable values.It looks like I need to step through the actual java file to inspect variable values. I tried to import the src folder (JAVA_HOME\src) in my JDK installation folder into my project, but that didn't work. Eclipse still goes straight to the class file. Any idea how to setup JRE src files so I can step through?

**Update:** 
I was able to partially resolve the issue. I am now able to step through the java src files. In order to do this, I ran the program in debug mode, set a random breakpoint in the class file that eclipse was referencing. When execution hits the breakpoint, in debug view under debug tab, right click the stacktrace for the current method and pick 'Edit source lookup'-> 'Add' to add the dir/proj that holds the src files. The default lookup path for some reason is set to JAVA_HOME/jre/lib, not sure how to fix the default path. In spite of this I still can't view local variables in the JRE src files.
A few points to elaborate about the local variables,they dont show up in the variables tab in debug view, when I click inspect/watch, I get a message saying 'x cannot be resovled to a variable.

Comment: What location did you give it for that entry on the Installed JREs preference page? JAVA_HOME or JAVA_HOME\jre? And which JDK is it?

Comment: Entry in Installed JREs preference page is JAVA_HOME only and the jdk is 1.7.

Comment: If it is a JDK, and you're pointing at its root, it should already be using the src.zip file that's there.

Answer (score 0):

This is *exactly* when you install and point your project and launch configuration at at **JDK** instead of a **JRE**.

Comment: I edited my question. The project is actually pointed at a JDK, my mistake in typing JRE. JAVA_HOME points to the JDK installation.